# Customized accent symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols, stacking-symbols

I would like to create a customized accent that is basically the symbol `\therefore`, i.e. I would like to have a letter with the "three-dot `\therefore` symbol" on top of it. I am new to LaTeX and I am not sure if there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: Please use backticks `\`` not `"` to format code in questions, answers or comments. They will then be displayed in the proper font.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for editing my question. Will keep your suggestions in mind when I post my questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`accents`](http://ctan.org/pkg/accents) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$\accentset{\therefore}{A}$

\end{document}
```

DON'T  use `\stackrel`, it is designed for math relations. And don't use `\overset` from `amsmath`, the postion is not correct.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. I will delete my answer with bad recommendations.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to show how trying to be really clever can get you shot in the foot:

```
$ \dot{\ddot{a}} $
\bye
```

[image]

`:-D`

Comment: Sounds like a great way to typeset the name of really, really heavy metal band.