# ‘A’ with a lower-case omega on top

Tags: math-mode, accents

How can I write this in TeX (or LaTeX)?

[image]

Also, strictly speaking, this is not part of my question, but has anyone seen notation like this?  If so, please answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87069/a-with-something-that-looks-like-a-lower-case-omega).

Comment: Does `\stackrel{\omega}{A}` help? `:)`

Comment: Close, but the omega is a bit off to the left.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customized accent symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16744/customized-accent-symbol)

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}
$\accentset{\omega}{A}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\overset{\omega}{A}
```

Never seen such a beast.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `\stackrel` with some movement magic:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\stackrel{\enskip\omega}{A}\]
\end{document}
```

with result:

[image: result]

Or if you need it sans serif italic like you've shown:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[\stackrel{\,\,\omega}{\textsf{\textit{A}}}\]
\end{document}
```

A very nice solution would be to use package [accents](http://ctan.org/pkg/accents), that prevents you from using any movement magic, als long as you are using math fonts only:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}
Nice:
\[\accentset{\omega}{A}\]
Not so nice:
\[\accentset{\omega}{\textsf{\textit{A}}}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\overset` like this: `$\overset{\omega}{A}$` but the result will not be great (the `A` is slanted and therefore the centering looks off. I like `\operatorname*` better, since it doesn't make the `A` slanted. You can use it like:

```
\[
  \operatorname*{A}^\omega
\]
```

The results look like this (`\overset` above, `\operatorname` below):

[image: overset vs operatorname]

I have never seen the notation before by the way.

Comment: With `\operatorname` you get wrong spacing.

Comment: What, exactly, is rather wrong?

Comment: @PaulReiners: The spacing to the left and right of the `A` will be off. If you feel the omega is off to the left, it's not. Just looks that way because the `A` is slanted. I like it better with the `A` upright. You could use `\overset{\omega}{\textrm{A}}` to make it look like the `\operatorname` approach and still get correct spacing.

By the way, if you want to respond to someone (in this case egreg) use @egreg to have him notified.

Comment: @PaulReiners An operator carries with it spacing rules that are different from those regarding an ordinary symbol. Compare `$A\operatorname*{A}$` and `$AA$`.

Comment: Why not `\overset{\omega}{\mathrm{A}}`, without abusing `\operatorname`?